# Can you dynamically resize an ElastiCache cluster with (cluster mode enabled)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

According to this doc:

> Currently, however, unlike Redis (cluster mode disabled) clusters,
>   once a Redis (cluster mode enabled) cluster is created, its structure
>   cannot be altered in any way; you cannot add or delete nodes or
>   shards. If you need to add or delete nodes, or change node types, you
>   must create the cluster anew. ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/CacheNodes.NodeGroups.html))

However, this doc seemingly describes a process to add shards to your cluster:

> By using online resharding and shard rebalancing with Amazon
>   ElastiCache for Redis version 3.2.10, you can scale your ElastiCache
>   for Redis (cluster mode enabled) dynamically with no downtime. This
>   approach means that your cluster can continue to serve requests even
>   while scaling or rebalancing is in process. ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/redis-cluster-resharding-online.html))

I'm presumably missing something since I've been staring at this for so long, but what is it?

Answer (score 4):

ElastiCache docs are way out of date; new announcements change what's available even when the three-year old docs remain unchanged. Redis on ElastiCache introduced support for online resizing in 2017. From [the announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-elasticache-update-online-resizing-for-redis-clusters/):

> You can now adjust the number of shards in a running ElastiCache for
>   Redis cluster while the cluster remains online and responding to
>   requests. This gives you the power to respond to changes in traffic
>   and data volume without having to take the cluster offline or to start
>   with an empty cache. You can also rebalance a running cluster to
>   uniformly redistribute slot space without changing the number of
>   shards.

I wish they'd update their 2015 (!) docs, but at any rate, this is the latest we have on the subject. As of October 19, 2018, on a cluster with cluster mode enabled:

You can:

- Scale out (add shards)
- Scale in (remove shards)
- Rebalance (move keys among shards)
- Online resharding and shard balancing

You cannot:

- Scale up/down (change node type)
- Upgrade your engine
- Configure shards independently

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/redis-cluster-resharding-online.html